# How to show a UIAlertView with confirm message and yes/no button in cocos2d for android?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d iOS I have done something like this, which is working fine for iOS.

```
-(void)showConfirmAlert
{  
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
  [alert setTitle:@"Confirm"];
  [alert setMessage:@"Do you pick Yes or No?"];
  [alert setDelegate:self];
  [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
  [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
    yes
  }
  else if (buttonIndex == 1)
  {
    no   
  }
}
```

How can I to use same `UIAlertView` in cocos2d-android (C++)?

Comment: I suppose you mean cocos2d-x because cocos2d-android is written in Java? Or did you meant to say Java, not C++?

Comment: Yes, it is for cocos2d-x for android in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
    private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
    builder.setMessage("Do you pick Yes or No?");   

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveEventAction = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Yes action here
        }
    };

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeEventAction = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // No action here
        }
    };

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", positiveEventAction);
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", negativeEventAction);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
    int icon = R.drawable.icon; // Optional
    dialog.setIcon(icon);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: this looks like Java, poster asked about C++

Comment: Sorry, I mistook your question. Take a look at this article http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/04/show-alert-in-cocos2d-android/

Comment: Hi Leonvian, I want to code in c++, not in java. Because i am using cocos2d-x for android.You send me link of the cocos2d-android which is deprecated.